# OneDrive only shows "OneDrive user" as editor in version history (but no specific username)

Tags: onedrive, version-control, microsoft-excel-365

I share a few Excel files through OneDrive. We only access the files via browser to open them in Excel 365. When you go to the version history of a file and check a specific previous version of a file:

[image]

it gives you the option to download and restore and shows the username of the editor (the user who edited the file) in this case `Alb`:

[image]

Unfortunately for some users, OneDrive will only show `OneDrive user`:

[image]

How can I enable all users to be shown with their user name in the version history?

**Update1:** it seems to be a problem with the rights management. for the particular user it seems the username is entered correctly (they can see their own username in the version history) but not shown to other users.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I enable all users to be shown with their user name in the version history?

You actually can't.  However, the users in question. can correct their settings themselves on their machine.

> This procedure changes the related settings for all Office apps, regardless of which app you are using when you change them.
>
> 1. Click File > Options.
> 2. Under Personalize your copy of Microsoft Office, type a new name in the User name box.

[image]

Source: [Change the author name for documents, presentations, or workbooks](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-author-name-for-documents-presentations-or-workbooks-0ad23fe7-b82e-40c4-b9d9-391fec971a54)

Comment: There is no option "Personalize your copy of Microsoft Office"

Comment: @Albin - Yes; There is I am using Excel 365 (current build) and I verified it exists before submitting this answer

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I found the article before I posted my question and didn't find the option. Sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes. Unfortunately it still didn't work, even if I change the name here and use the "always" check box, it will not use it (but with the screen shot I gave it at least  a +1 now). Any ideas?

Comment: see update1 in my question: the user name was entered correctly but for other users it only appears as "Onedrive user"